# Does HDFS needs 3 times the data space?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I was attending a course on Hadoop and MapReduce on Udacity.com and the instructor mentioned that In HDFS to reduce the point of failures each block is replicated 3 times in Database. Is it true for real?? Does it mean that If I have 1 petabytes of Logs I will need 3 Petabytes of Storage?? Beacuse that will cost me more

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is true, **HDFS** requires space for each redundant copy and requires copies to achieve failure tolerance *and* data locality during processing.

But this is not necessarily true about **MapReduce**, which can run on other file systems like S3 or Azure blobs for instance. It is HDFS that requires the 3 copies.

Answer (score 1):

By default, HDFS conf parameter `dfs.replication` is set with value 3. That allow fault tolerance, disponibility, etc... ([All parameters of HDFS here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml))

But in install time, you could set the parameter in 1, and HDFS don't make replicas of your data. With dfs.replication=1, 1 petabyte is storaged in the same space amount.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's true. So say if you have say 4 machines with datanodes running on them, then by default replication will happen in other two machines at random as well. If you don't want that, you can switch it to 1 by setting `dfs.replication` property in hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is because HDFS replicates data when you store it. The default replication factor for hdfs is 3, which you can find in hdfs-site.xml file under dfs.replication property. You can set this value to 1 or 5 as per your requirement.

Data replication is much useful as if some node particularly goes down, you will have the copy of data available on other node/nodes for processing.